# Thirring-Lens 1918 Paper seems to be wrong in the numeric results. Am I misreading it?

Tags: general-relativity, frame-dragging

The 1918 paper that is often considered a basis for frame dragging (a copy is at http://www.neo-classical-physics.info/uploads/3/4/3/6/34363841/lense_thirring_-_lense-thirring_effect.pdf) seems to say that the moon's orbit slides around the Earth at 2" per century, which I assume is 2 arcseconds per century.  But that is way too much.  The LAGEOS satellites only have their orbits slide around at 3"/century (31 milliarcseconds per year) and they are way closer to the Earth. Am I misreading something, or is this a recognized historic math error that doesn't impact the theory?